# Python: Why are numpy arrays taking much larger memory space than pandas dataframe of the same dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to read a dataset from a pickle file into a dataframe and then divide it into input and labels as numpy arrays. But the numpy array is taking too large space than the dataframe. My DataFrame consists of one column. The column has 16870 rows. Each row is a 150528 size numpy array. I printed the size of the dataframe, it is 1754640 bytes. I performed following operations on the dataframe:

```py
arr_to_img = lambda img: np.reshape(img,(224,224,3))
imgs = np.array(list(map(arr_to_img,df_imgs["Images"])))
def bgr2lab(img):
    lab = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    return lab[:,:,0],lab[:,:,1:]
LAB= list(map(bgr2lab,imgs))
X = np.array([cv2.cvtColor(x[0],cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) for x in LAB ])
Y = np.array([x[1] for x in LAB ])
```

But when I printed the size of X, it shows 2539407504 bytes!! How is that possible? Both are of same shape, only X has the flattened array back to 3D. Also, shouldn't array be smaller than DF as DFs have other extra info? So why is the array taking so large space. Even the total size of the images in jpeg format is way small, around 420MB. Why is this happening and how do I avoid this? I am having trouble training model with the data as the notebook runs out of memory

Comment: How exactly did you determine the sizes?

Comment: @DYZ `sys.getsizeof(var)`

Comment: `getsizeof` is a newbie trap. It doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica what does it do then? also, the kaggle and colab notebooks are running out of memory even though I delete the dataframe and in between variables after use

Comment: Beware that when reading a JPEG image, it decompresses, costing easily 10x more represented in-memory than it did on disk.

Comment: `getsizeof` makes no attempt to consider the sizes of other objects that are "logically part of" the object you give it as an argument.

Comment: @PascalGetreuer so what is the best method to use large image dataset?

Comment: Look into generators, or smaller batches